# In a triangle, $\Delta ABC$ we are given that $3 \sin A + 4 \cos B = 6$ and $4 \sin B + 3\cos A = 1$. Then what is the measure of angle $C$?

Tags: trigonometry

> In a triangle, $\Delta ABC$ we are given that $3 \sin A + 4 \cos B = 6$ and $4 \sin B + 3\cos A = 1$. Then what is the measure of angle $C$?

On squaring and adding both the equations,we get

$$9 + 16 + 24 \sin (A + B) = 37\implies$$

$$\sin (A + B) =
\frac{1}{2}\implies A+B=\frac{\pi}{6}\implies C=5\pi/6$$

But,in answer key it is given that $C=\pi/6$

I wanted to know where i'm wrong.

**I've also gone through [Finding $C$ if $ 3\sin A + 4\cos B = 6 $ and $ 3\cos A + 4\sin B = 1 $ in a triangle $ABC$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687156/finding-c-if-3-sin-a-4-cos-b-6-and-3-cos-a-4-sin-b-1-in-a-tria) ,but here also,i didn't get my answer.**

Comment: It is not true that $\sin(A+B)=\frac 12\implies A+B=\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sin(A+B) = \frac{1}{2}$ has **two** solutions in $(0,\pi)$, that are $A+B \in \{\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}\}$.

Now check which of them satisfies original equations. Lets suppose $A+B = \frac{\pi}{6}$. In triangle, all angles are positive, so both $0 < A,B \lt \frac{\pi}{6}$. This implies that

- $0 < \sin A< \frac{1}{2}$
- $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} < \cos B < 1$

From first equation,

$$3\sin(A) +4\cos(B) = 6$$

Maximum value of LHS is $4+\frac{3}{2}$, that too not achievable, and it is less than $6$. So this equation is never satisfied for $A+B = \frac{\pi}{6}$.

Similarly analyse the equations for second solution, that is $A+B = \frac{5\pi}{6}$

Comment: the first equation is $3 \sin A + 4 \cos B = 6$

Comment: @Arnaldo I have edited the answer! Thanks! Hope it is correct now.

Comment: You should also analyse $5\pi/6$. The problem would have no solution.

Comment: That is true, but I am already tired. OP will do it for himself :)